# how do i create a approval process on Quote Line Item

Tags: approval-process

I Need a small Help, MY requirement is to create a approval process on Quote Line Items, (Whenever the discount is more than 10%) it should be automatically assigned to the Approver

I have designed a criteria and activated it, but it  is not showing in Approver Related List

Comment: What criteria did you design to account for this? It's currently not possible to have approval processes on the standard Quote Line Item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process to approve **Quote Line Item** fields should be attributed to the **Quote** object. You'll want to use a *Rollup Summary Field* on the related Quote:

[image]

Then use this field for criteria on the **Quote** approval process:

[image]

Comment: Hello Mr Olapo  I tried like you said, but i cannot see the Approver in the Approval Related List, is there someting i am missing, i activated the quote approval process

Comment: Could you post screenshot of what you're referring to by no "Approver int he Approval Related List"?